# How to call gnuplot for different scripts independently

Tags: shell-script, gnuplot

i am using GNUplot to create figures from data points, GNUplot works with simple scripts that contain simple parameters/variables like the range of the x or y axis, settings for line colors and stuff like that.
When i call one of those scripts like:

```
gnuplot script1.gpl
```

it works fine, but when i run

```
gnuplot *.gpl
```

to run it for all files in the current directory, i got problems because some if the settings are transfered from one script to the next. This is probably because gnuplot does not resets the parameters and if i do not overwrite them explicitly in the following script, the settings are still there.
Thats why i tried to run it differently using find:

```
find . -name '*.gpl' -exec gnuplot {} \;
```

but again i get the same problematic results. So what i need is a command that runs the same command for each file but in a way as if it where called manually for each file.

Comment: You may want to look up the `reset` and `reset session` Gnuplot commands

Comment: Why not make your scripts executable and start them with `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -c`? Personally, I tend to make them Bash scripts that set up some variables, and use `gnuplot << END` followed by the plot script, followed by `END`, so that I can insert environment variables (using shell syntax, `$name`) into the script. But executable scripts anyway. I even often run them from `Makefile`s.. Let me know if you need a complex example.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `find` to work as per a single call.  If there are no intermediate files being created I would suggest adding a bash (or other shell) prefix, to force it to be run in a sub-shell.   Or you can try the following:

```
for i in *.gpl
do 
  ( gnuplot "$i" )
done
```

The brackets will force a sub-shell, but I don't think it should be required.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how `find`'s  `-exec command '{}]' \;` is expected to behave versus the alternative `-exec command '{}' +` where `find`'s  results are appended to create a singe multi-argument command (or as many as possible at least -minimising the instances of `command` being executed). This is also stated in `man find`. OP's `find`'s behaviour seems oddish.

Comment: I guess it may depend on the commands he is using inside the .gpl files.  Unfortunately, I can not post comments to ask simple questions.